# How to Run cucumber test cases from jar? Jar not able to find stepdefinitions?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, jar, cucumber

While Running Cucumber Test cases from Jar its not able to find step definations?

```
project-root
│
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   └── java
│   │       └── com.example.package
│   │            └── Main.java (Cucumber CLI usage)
│   └── test
│       ├── java
│       │   └── com.example.package
│       │       └── runner
│       │           └── YourTestRunner.java (Test Runner class)
│       │       └── stepdefinition
│       │           └── YourStepDefinitions.java (Cucumber step definitions)
│       └── resources
│           └── features
│               └── your.feature
```

I have folder structure like above .

Executing using

```
package com.example;
import io.cucumber.core.cli.Main;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        // Pass your command-line arguments to the Cucumber CLI Main class
        String[] cucumberArgs = {
            "--glue", "com.example.package.runner.YourTestRunner",
            "--glue", "com.example.package.stepdefinition", 
            "classpath:/features",
            "-t", "@mytag"
        };
        Main.run(cucumberArgs, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
    }
}
```

gradle.build

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'com.springframework.boot' version ''
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version ''
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '7.1.2' 
 
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation "io.cucumber:cucumber-java8:7.xx"
    testImplementation "io.cucumber:cucumber-java:7.xx"
    implementation "io.cucumber:cucmber-spring:7.xx"
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}


task buildCustomFatJar(type: Jar) {
    zip64 = true
    from sourceSets.main.output
    from sourceSets.test.output
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }

    // Set the main class for the JAR
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': ' com.example.package.Main' 
    }
    with jar
}
```

Running jar

```
java -jar custom-jar-name.jar
```

result

> 5 Scenarios (5 Undefined)
> 10 Steps (5 skipped, 5 undefined)

Since there was no main method so created main class with main method.
Expecting to run test cases from jar.

Comment: When you unzip the jar file, what does the file structure look like?

Comment: I suspect that when building the jar, you are overwriting files in `META-INF/services`  instead of merging them. See https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/2689

Comment: Thank you, Indeed that was issue. I resolve by creating shadow jar and using mergeServiceFiles()